# ⚠ functions: failed to create function add HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

Tags: function, cloud

I have this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this simply index.js

```
"use strict";
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.add = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hola mundo')
})
```

I'm trying to deploy this function but this happend

MacBook-Pro-de-Fernando-2:functions xxxxxx$ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'yyyyyy-f08c8'...

i deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

functions@ lint /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/YYYYYY/yyyyyy/functions eslint .

✔ functions: Finished running predeploy script. i functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled... ✔ functions: all necessary APIs are enabled i functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... i functions: packaged functions (39.76 KB) for uploading ✔ functions: functions folder uploaded successfully i functions: creating function add... ⚠ functions: failed to create function add HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run: firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me, and fixed by:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
```